# How can I see how many users have a particular association in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I'm trying to figure out how I can use the Rails console to get the number of users that have two particular associations.  Here's my conditions:

A `User` can have many `DropboxUser` accounts linked and many `DriveUser` accounts linked to their account via a foreign key.  In my model declaration, both `DropboxUser` and `DriveUser` `belongs_to :user`.  In conjunction with the previous statement, a `User` `has_many :dropbox_users` and `has_many :drive_users`.  I know I have all of my models linked, so now **I want to know how I can find out how many `User` accounts have both a `DropboxUser` account and a `DriveUser` account associated with them**.

Here's some of the code I've tried (unsuccessfully):

```
User.count(:conditions => "dropbox_users.uid='user.id' AND drive_users.uid='user_id'")
```

Perhaps I was headed in the right direction with my last query, perhaps not.  It told me `no such column: dropbox_users.uid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join `dropbox_users` to be able to query on it.

```
User.joins(:dropbox_users).joins(:drive_users).count
```

Also, since `joins` uses an `INNER JOIN`, it will only return records that have both Dropbox and Drive accounts.